# Is ethminer malware?

Tags: ether

I just scanned the PC using MBAM and it detected the ZIP file of ethminer (only the zip, not the extracted folder) as malware.
Now, after used MBAM to delete the zip, suddenly the ethminer itself won't work! (huh?!) -It created a new DAG file after the restart! I didn't touch the ethminer files in the extracted folder, but from some reason it stopped working, and created a new DAG suddenly.. ?
What is going on?

Also, I downloaded ethminer from here:

[Ethminer from a certain blog](http://cryptomining-blog.com/tag/ethminer-cuda-download/)

And realized that there is a completely different download on the GitHub page!? as can be seen here:
[Ethminer from GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/releases)

Answer (score -1):

Often, antivirus will pick up mining software as malware because it’s common for a virus to mine on your computer so the creator gets free coins. Sounds like something must have broke when the antivirus deleted the software. Try to clean install FROM THE GITHUB not a random site